# How to avoid Gensim Simple Preprocess to remove digits?

Tags: python, gensim

I am having some problems in preprocessing some data with `gensim.utils.simple_preprocess`.
In a few words, I noticed that the `simple_preprocess` function removes the digits from my text, but I don't want to!
For instance, I have this code:

```
import gensim
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

my_text = ["I am doing activity number 1", "Instead, I am doing the number 2"]

def gen_words(texts):
    final = []
    for text in texts:
        new = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text, deacc=True, min_len=1)
        final.append(new)
    return (final)

solution = gen_words(my_text)

print (solution)
```

The output is the following:

```
[['i', 'am', 'doing', 'activity', 'number'], ['instead', 'i', 'am', 'doing', 'the', 'number']]
```

I would like instead to have this as a solution:

```
[['i', 'am', 'doing', 'activity', 'number', '1'], ['instead', 'i', 'am', 'doing', 'the', 'number', '2']]
```

How to avoid seeing the digits erased from my code? I have also tried setting the `min_len=0` but still is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simple_preprocess()` function is just one rather simple convenience option for tokenizing text from a string, into a list-of-tokens.

It's not especially well-tuned for any particular need – and it has no configurable option to retain tokens that don't match its particular hardcoded pattern (`PAT_ALPHABETIC`) which rules-out tokens with leading digits.

Many projects will want to apply their own tokenization/preprocessing instead, better suited to their data & problem domain. If you need ideas for how to start, youc can consult the actual source code for `simple_preprocess()` (and other functions it relies upon like `tokenize()` & `simple_tokenize()`) that Gensim uses:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/utils.py

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @gojomo. At this point, maybe it is better for me to search for other solutions. I saw that spaCy allows to customize the with the nlp pipeline, maybe I can try with that.